# JSON4Scala extract value from nested Object

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to parse json with this library https://github.com/momodi/Json4Scala

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  current: {pageviews: 5, time: 50, id: 'jafh784'},
  allTime: {pageviews: 20, time: 438, id: 'adsf6447'}
}

val json = Json.parse(x.getString("user"))
json.asMap("current").asMap("pageviews").asInt
```

It is not working and I have tried several combinations of the above. I tried to use some other libraries but they were even less clear to me. The schema of the json varies but the page views is always in the same location. I am open for suggestions of another library.

Edit: I read about using case classes for nested objects but the schema is not exact across all my json. Can I just use a case class and only declare a minimum of keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Play Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) allows you to do it without having to specify models:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val raw = """{
  "current": {"pageviews": 5, "time": 50, "id": "jafh784"},
  "allTime": {"pageviews": 20, "time": 438, "id": "adsf6447"}
}"""

val json = Json.parse(raw).as[JsObject]
val currentPageviews = (json \ "current" \ "pageviews").as[Int]

println(currentPageviews) // 5
```

[Here here is a link to a live example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FGasPA08TCSuUyYIdo7FBQ).

To include the PlayJson dependency add this to your build sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.6.2"
```

(There are also build for `2.12`)

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate you using the json I provided.